# $\mathbb{C}$ as a quotient of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ by the principal ideal of $x^2 + 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Aluffi illustrates (circa III.4.2) the division by monic polynomials in a commutative polynomial ring $R$ by showing that $\frac{R[x]}{(f(x))} \cong R^{\oplus d}$ as groups, where $f(x) \in R[x]$ is monic, $d = \deg f(x)$, and $(a)$ is the principal ideal generated by $a$.

As a particular example, he shows that $\mathbb{C} \cong \frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2+1)}$ as rings. He further explains the intuition behind this isomorphism:

> The point is that the polynomial equation $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$; the quotient $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2 + 1)}$ produces a ring containing a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ and in which the polynomial does have roots (that is, $\pm$ the class of $x$ in the quotient).

I'm not sure I follow this. Indeed, $x^2 + 1$ does not have roots in $\mathbb{R}$, but

- I only know that $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2 + 1)}$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ because I know $\frac{\mathbb{R}[x]}{(x^2 + 1)} \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$. Is there another nice way to see this, perhaps tied specifically to the structure of $\mathbb{R}$?
- What would it mean for the polynomial (and I assume that's $x^2 + 1$ that's meant) to have roots in this quotient? This quotient is just a set of cosets of $(x^2 + 1)$ (that is, a set of sets $\{ g(x) + h(x)(x^2 + 1) \mid h(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x] \}$ for each $g(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$) that happens to be a ring. What would be a root here and how would it relate to $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: Note that modding out $(x^2+1)$ basically means to introduce the relation $x^2+1 = 0$. And where do we know that from? Right: $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: It contains a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ because the canonical injection $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is an injection.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about the canonical injection, that's indeed nicer! Re the first point — I don't have enough intuition with the quotients yet to see that factoring by an ideal generated by $a$ implies the relation $a = 0$. Is it "just because" $a$ itself lives in $(a)$, and $(a)$ is the zero of the quotient by it?

Comment: If we mod out $(x^2 + 1)$, then we're saying that $x^2+1 + (x^2+1) = 0 + (x^2+1)$, so basically in the quotient structure $x^2+1 = 0$ which is the induced relation that we get. I'm not sure if this explanation was helpful, feel free to ask if it wasn't. Quotients can be weird at first but you'll definitely get used to it over time :)

Comment: It definitely is helpful. I wish you wrote this as an answer that sticks out better than a comment in case somebody stumbles upon this question (and so that I could also accept it :)). I'm yet not sure what exactly Aluffi meant by the "that is, $\pm$ the class of $x$ in the quotient", cause zero is the class of $x^2 + 1$ just as you said, but that's probably less relevant — unless there's a good explanation for that too.

Comment: Basically he means that $x+(x^2+1)$ and $-x + (x^2+1)$ are solutions to the polynomial equation $t^2 + 1 = 0$. And note that we want $t^2 + 1 = 0$ to have solutions because these solutions represent $\pm i \in \mathbb{C}$! (So in the canonical isomorphism we will have $\bar{x} \mapsto i$ and $-\bar{x} \mapsto -i$.) And sure, I will write it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common example to demonstrate quotient rings (and to see that polynomial rings are quite universal).

- The quotient $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ contains a copy of $\mathbb{R}$ because of the canonical injection $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$.
- By modding out $(x^2+1)$, we introduce the relation $x^2+1 = 0$. This means that $x + (x^2+1)$ and $-x + (x^2+1)$ solve the polynomial equation $t^2 + 1 = 0$, i.e. $\pm \bar{x}$ fulfil the relation $x^2 + 1$. We wish to have this because solutions to that equation represent exactly $\pm i \in \mathbb{C}$! The isomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb{C}$ will hence map $\pm \bar{x} \mapsto \pm i$.